# Using $_GET for pagination, adding one to it

Tags: php, pagination

So what i am doing is creating a pagination in one php file.

i'm using $_GET for this:

```
if ( $_GET["page"] === "3" ) echo 'href="#"';
else echo 'href=?page=' . $_GET["page"] + 1 . '"';
```

This code is used for making the side arrow's work

[image: Pagination]

when i am on ?page=3 the script echo's href"#" like expected, but when i am on every other page the script echos

> 1"

I have checked the script a few times and don't see any error's.

I think i am just doing something stupid, but I really don't know what.

I hope you want to help me!

Comment: `if ($_GET['page']=="3") { echo 'href="#"'; } else { echo 'href=?page='.$_GET['page'] + 1.'"'; }`

Comment: The brackets are not the problem here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a string and an integer with "+" inside a concat with no parenthesis

change it to

```
if ( $_GET["page"] === "3" ) echo 'href="#"'; else echo 'href="?page=' . ($_GET["page"]+ 1) . '"';
```

Answer (score 3):

Your else is wrong with the quotes and you need the brackets around the `+1`:

```
else echo 'href=?page=' . $_GET["page"] + 1 . '"';
// should be
else echo 'href="?page='.( $_GET["page"] + 1 ).'"';
                ^
```

Comment: Woops, mistype when I was trying to fix it. But it still output's 1#

Comment: Thanks very much! (Ayame__ too!) this worked! My way worked before though, which is pretty weird. But ok! Thanks guy's you made my day!

Comment: I kinda ment this to be the answer lol. But Ayame__'s works too

Comment: I've set Ayame__'s answer as the solution because it gives a brief overview what I did wrong, and is,in my opinion, better for other people that have this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't use "===", if `$_GET["page"]` is int your code return false. And you forget one quote.

Try this :

```
echo 'href="'.( ($_GET["page"] == 3) ? '#' : '?page='.($_GET["page"]+1) ).'"';
```

Read this : [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis)

Comment: Actually, there's no error in that in his code. $_GET variables are all strings, and in his code he compares to string 3 (`"3"`). Typechecking has no added value here, but it's no wrong